# Stochastic Analysis: proof using integral approximation

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Let $t_1<t_2 \in [0,T]$, $f(t)\ge0$ and $Z_t$ an increasing process with $Z_0= 0$.

We have clearly that
\begin{equation}
\int_{[0,t_2[}f(s)dZ_s \ge \chi_{t_1<T}(Z_{t_2} - Z_{t_1})\min_{t_1\le s \le t_2}f(s)
\end{equation}holds.

In a paper I'm reading the authors state based on this and using the fact that $Z_{t_1}\ge0$ it follows that
\begin{equation}
\int_{[0,t_2[}f(s)dZ_s \ge \chi_{t_1<T}Z_{t_2}(\min_{t_1 \le s \le t_2}(f(s) - f(t_2)) + f(t_2))
\end{equation} holds.

I'm confused how that can be, it seems like an error! Surely since $Z_{t_1}\ge0$ we must have $(Z_{t_2} - Z_{t_1}) \le Z_{t_2}?$ Would appreciate any insight into anything I may have glossed over here!

For reference I am talking about the beginning of page 264 of the following paper: Boetius, Frederik, and Michael Kohlmann. "[Connections between optimal stopping and singular stochastic control](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304414998000490)." Stochastic Processes and their Applications 77.2 (1998): 253-281.

Comment: I see how to match the hypothesis at the top of p. 264 with yours, but I don't see why the conclusion matches.  The notation is sufficiently involved that I can buy it, but are you sure that what you have written matches their conclusion $J_f \ge \chi_{\sigma < T}(Z_\sigma^x - Z_\sigma^{x - \delta})f(\sigma) + \delta I_5(\delta) + \delta I_6(\delta)$?

Comment: Hi LSpice, to give you more context: When they are writing $J_f \ge \chi_{\sigma<T}(Z^x_\sigma - Z^{x-\delta}_\sigma)f(\sigma) + \delta I_5(\delta) + \delta I_6(\delta),$ by plugging in the terms we supposedly have $\chi_{\sigma^\delta<T}(X^*_{\sigma^\delta} - Z^{x-\delta}_\sigma)f(\sigma^\delta) + \int_{[0,\sigma^\delta[}f(s)d\xi^*_s \ge \chi_{\sigma^\delta<T}(X^*_{\sigma^\delta} - Z^{x-\delta}_{\sigma^\delta})f(\sigma^\delta) + \chi_{\sigma<T}\xi^*_{\sigma^\delta}f(\sigma^\delta) + \chi_{\sigma<T}\xi^*_{\sigma^\delta}\min_{\sigma \le s \le \sigma^\delta}(f(s) - f(\sigma^\delta))$

Comment: where $\xi^*_t$ is my increasing process with $\xi^*_0 = 0$ and $\sigma<\sigma^\delta.$

Comment: I also have to admit I don't understand the $\chi$ notation, and the authors don't explain it that I could see.  What does it mean?  In particular, is $\chi_{t_1 < T}Z_{t_2}$ a product, or the evaluation of a function?

Comment: Yes I found it confusing too! I believe they are using it like so: $\chi_{A}=1$ if $A$ is true and $\chi_{A}=0$ otherwise. So yes $\chi_{t_1<T}Z_{t_2}$ is a product.

Comment: Huh.  Assuming that there's no deeper meaning to $\chi$ than that sort of Iverson indicator (but why, since $t_1$ already comes from $[0, T]$?), and that there's no extra structure that's hidden here, I agree that one can't deduce the latter from the former.  Indeed, the latter is false:  taking $Z_s = s$, we have that $\int_{[0, 2[} \chi_{s \in [1, 2]}\mathrm ds = 1$ is strictly less than $\chi_{1 < 2}\cdot2\cdot1 = 2$.

Comment: Yes I agree with you. I am wringing my hands making sense of this hieroglyphic paper for a dissertation, no one seemed to understand my plight. Apparently it has 57 citations, I wonder if the 57+ authors cracked this issue. In any case thanks a lot for your time LSpice, I really appreciate it!

Comment: You might try passing over this and seeing if the rest of the paper hangs together, and, once you have read the whole paper, contacting the authors to see if they agree that this is an error or, if not, what extra structure there is that makes it work.

Comment: Thank you LSpice, that is a great suggestion. I am using a workaround for the time being by just writing $\int_{[0,t_2[}f(s)d\xi^*_s \ge \xi^*_{t_2}\min_{0 \le s \le t_2}f(s)$ (since $\xi^*_0=0$).